# Google Cloud console throwing errors

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have a Google cloud project, but every time I log in to the console and try to click on my project, I get a pop-up asking me to send feedback due to some error.

I have already given feedback twice about the problem in the last 48 hours. Didn't know where else to ask. Anyone else experiencing similar problems?

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information than that.  What operating system are you using, what browser are you using, what is the exact error message you are getting, what is the url you are visiting to log into the console?  Did it work before and suddenly stop working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeffrey: we noticed your problem in our logs before you posted this, and we're actively working on getting a fix out for you.

Comment: Thanks quasistoic. Good to know.